# (audio) Files transferred to Motorola Milestone does not stay there

Tags: ubuntu, usb-drive, removable-storage

I'm using gpodder to manage podcast on Ubuntu machine (thinkpad laptop). When I transfer files to the phone I see the files on the phone sd card via ubuntu file manager, however, when I disconnect the phone and browse the files from android I don't see the file. Connecting the phone back to the machine and browsing to the appropriate folder, I don't see the files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you unmounting the SD card before you unplug the phone? It sounds like the files are still buffered and you're disconnecting the device before they actually get written -- this is the main reason you need to sync/unmount drives before disconnecting them

Comment: I can't account for all the cases (though I think I did unmount), in the last time it happened, I shutdown the computer.